# EventProcessorHost using in webjob with multiple instances - giving exception Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.LeaseLostException

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

I am using EventProcessorHost in webjob with multiple instances - giving exception Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.LeaseLostException. Perticularly only one instance is giving this exception.

It is not giving any exception when I am running it as single instances

Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.LeaseLostException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.LeaseLostException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.<>c__DisplayClass33.<RenewLeaseImpl>b__32(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:line 3186
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 299
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.EndRenewLease(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:line 1982
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line 114
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BlobLeaseManager.d__23.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BlobLeaseManager.d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BlobLeaseManager.d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at RoutingServiceWebJob.DataProcessorFactory.EventHubDataProcessor.d__37.MoveNext() in d:\a\1\s\RoutingServiceWebJob\DataProcessorFactory\EventHubDataProcessor.cs:line 163

I am reading messages one at a time. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to avoid this by setting the Host name to be a unique string.  For example

```
var eventProcessorHostName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: Every restart, you get another hostname like this. Does that not lead to issues with the offset?